# cgminer configure script can't find libusb, which is installed

Tags: configure, autoconf, automake, iconv, cgminer

I'm trying to build cgminer on a RISC-V 64 system. I had compiled it fine on aarch64 (Raspberry pi).

After installing libusb-dev and libusb1.1-1.dev, and running ldconfig, I still get this error from the configure script:

```
    checking whether NULL can be used in arbitrary expressions... yes^M
    checking for egrep... (cached) /usr/bin/grep -E^M
    checking for syslog.h... yes^M
    checking for size_t... yes^M
    checking for working alloca.h... yes^M
    checking for alloca... yes^M
    checking for pthread_create in -lpthread... yes^M
    checking for library containing addstr... -lncurses^M
    ./configure: line 10668: syntax error near unexpected token `LIBUSB,'^M
    ./configure: line 10668: `                      PKG_CHECK_MODULES(LIBUSB, libusb-1.0, AC_DEFINE(HAVE_LIBUSB, 1, [Define if you have libusb-1.0]), AC_MSG_ERROR([Could not find usb library - please install libusb-1.0]))'
```

At various points before this, autogen.sh urged me to re-run autoupdate, which I did. The autogen.sh script in general did not want to run to completion either.

Has anyone seen a syntax error in an automatically generated configure script before?

Answer (score 0):

The `configure` script has been generated from `configure.ac` on a system without the `pkg.m4` file installed, so the `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` macro has not been expanded into shell code and the generated `configure` script is broken because it contains non-shell syntax.

(The presence `^M` characters also point to some kind of Windows line ending weirdness, which might or might not become an actual problem once you fix the `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` error.)

The fix to properly expand the `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` macro consists of two parts:

- Upstream cgminer should fix the `configure.ac` file to include the line

  ```
  m4_pattern_forbid([PKG_CHECK_MODULES])dnl
  ```

  The line before the `PKG_CHECK_MODULES([LIBUSB], ...)` line would be a good place for that.

  This makes it impossible for `autoreconf` to generate such a broken `configure` file again.
- You can install `pkg.m4` and re-run `autoreconf` to regenerate `configure` from `configure.ac`. Then the `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` will be expanded into the proper shell code which can then work as intended.

  `pkg.m4` is probably part of a `-dev` or `-m4` development subpackage for the `pkgconf` or `pkgconfig` package.

It is always a good idea to `m4_pattern_forbid` any non-`AC_*` and non-`AM_*` macro used in `configure.ac`, so if this `configure.ac` does not do that for `PKG_CHECK_MODULES`, it might also fail to do that for other macros, so you might run into the same error with some other macro later. The fix is the same: Add a `m4_pattern_forbid` line to prevent the generation of broken `configure` files, and then regenerate `configure` with the appropriate `*.m4` files installed.